# The AD sync is not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, user-profile-service, adi

Environment: SharePoint 2016, one server with custom role

The user profile service is started ، some usres were imported when the farm installed,

Today, I tried to add a new user in the Same domain , it's not found!!!!

Comment: What type of Sync you configured? is it ADI or UPA Sync via MIM?

Comment: Started the User Profile Service! Do I need to configure UPS in SP 2016, I only need one way sync from AD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure the User Profile Sync service which can pull the users from AD to SharePoint. As you need one way sync then Active Directory Import option of UPA will work for you. There are couple of requirements to configure the ADI.

- You need a service account which should have Replicate Directory Changes permission in AD.
- You have to create User profile Service
- You have to configure the connections for all domain
- Map the properties which you want to import in SharePoint
- Run full sync.

Here is complete step by step guide by MSFT on it. [Step by Step: Active Directory Import for SharePoint 2013](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meacoex/2013/08/04/step-by-step-active-directory-import-for-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, , why I can get  some AD users without configure UP sync service? , What's the use of User Profile Service?

Comment: The User Profile service is a shared service in SharePoint Server that provides a central location for configuring and managing. If a user browse the sites then automatically with basic information. You have to create the user profile service application then configure the sync connections as i ,mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I restarted the timer service and the sync one way worked!